# Getter functions for properties and dataclass attributes

Tags: python

**tl;dr** I'm after a shorthand for `lambda x: x.bar`

If I have a class

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self) -> int:
        return 0
```

I can use `Foo.bar` as a first-class function for getting the `bar` attribute from a `Foo`, like

```
foo = Foo()
getter = Foo.bar
getter(foo)  # 0
```

This is useful when some function expects the data and getter as separate objects, and saves having to write `lambda x: x.bar()`. That's all fine. What I'd like is something similar with `@property`s and `@dataclass` attributes. Here's the same approach not working for properties

```
class Foo:
    @property
    def bar(self) -> int:
        return 0

foo = Foo()
getter = Foo.bar
getter(foo)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....py", line 16, in <module>
    getter(foo)
TypeError: 'property' object is not callable
```

Anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter):

```
>>> from operator import attrgetter

>>> getter = attrgetter('bar') 
>>> getter(foo)
0
```

The same approach naturally works with dataclass attributes as well:

```
>>> @dataclass
>>> class Baz:
...    bar: int

>>> getter(Baz(1))
1
```

Comment: `attrgetter`'s a good point, though I do wonder if there's a typed option